# How to install two mongodb instance in a single machine?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, terminal

I want to setup two versions of mongodb on my machine on different ports 
I already installed 4.0.5 version of the mongodb on my machine on port number 27018 but now I want to install the mongodb version 3.6 on my machine I'm installing it from this [link](https://harrytang.xyz/blog/upgrading-mongodb-ubuntu). It show me the error of that I have already installed mongodb latest version 4.0.5. error :-

```
mongodb-org is already the newest version (4.0.5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-headers-4.15.0-39 linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-39-generic
```

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
     0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.

How I install two instance on a single machine on different ports.

Comment: You don't need to install it again. Just start a new mongodb process with different port in mongo config.

Comment: @RahulSharma Can you write the commands please that how I will run the mongodb version 3.6 and 4.0.5 both?

Comment: @RahulSharma How it will differ between the versions?

Comment: My bad. I didn't go through the question properly. Probably, this link https://serverfault.com/questions/590576/installing-multiple-mongodb-versions-on-the-same-server might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Install via package manager two packages with different version may be impossible. At now may be easy and modern way to use docker.

Comment: Can you tell me that how I install it in my local machine

Comment: can you please tell me this thing without docker

Comment: you can compile mongod from source without install and run they with specific config. You must ensure that servers do not cross in runtime files and sockets.